# Conversion failed when converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, varchar

This appears to be a bug in SQL Server itself. I have a VERY simple function, whose job is to basically emulate `try_convert(datetime, string arg)`, since my customer won't allow setting the database to SQL Server 2012 compatibility.

I extracted out the start of the function and the test query, as follows:

```
create function spTryConvertDateTime (@pString varchar(255))
returns datetime
as
begin
   declare @iresult datetime = null;
   declare @string varchar(255) = ltrim(rtrim(isnull(@pString, '')));
   declare @datestring varchar(255);
   declare @timestring varchar(255);

   if len(@string) < 10
      return @iresult;

   set @datestring = left(@string, 10);

   if len(@string) >= 19
      set @timestring = substring(@string, 11, len(@string-10));

   return null;
end;
go

declare @v varchar(32) = '2017-10-31 00:00:00';
select dbo.spTryConvertDateTime(@v);
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2017-10-31 00:00:00' to data type int.

???  Where am I trying to convert ANYTHING to data type `int`?

What is going on? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code deep in the function:

```
len(@string-10)
```

(This is the end of the last line before the `return NULL`.)

You cannot subtract 10 from a string.  Hence the attempt to convert it to an integer.

Comment: DOH!  Thank you - don't know how long I stared at this and didn't see it.